# Is there an if-condition which can be used in Ajax?

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I am working on a web application that allows user to post message on a page. I have two ejs files:

1. index.ejs which has the form for user to put information and render a whole list of user name and messages from the db.
2. validation.ejs which help me to showing error messages with aJax(because I don't want the page to refresh when there is an error, as a result my list will go away), and I am using mongoose to store data, all the input requirement set up in mongoose.

When I submit an empty form, I got error messages showing('name cannot be empty','message cannot be empty'), but when I submit again with provided information, it is still showing the error, my question is: is there a way to use "if, else" condition in ajax that can either showing errors or successfully adding a user?

server.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const flash = require("express-flash");
const session = require("express-session");

mongoose.connect(
  "mongodb://localhost/messageDashboard",
  { useNewUrlParser: true },
);
const CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    commenter: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Commenter cannot be empty"],
    },
    comment: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Comment cannot be empty"],
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true },
);

const MessageSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Name cannot be empty"],
    },
    message: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Message cannot be empty"],
    },
    comments: [CommentSchema],
  },
  { timestamps: true },
);

const Message = mongoose.model("Message", MessageSchema);

var app = express();
app.set("views", __dirname + "/views");
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(flash());
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "keyboard cat",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { maxAge: 60000 },
  }),
);

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  Message.find({}, function(err, messages) {
    if (err) {
      res.redirect("/");
    } else {
      console.log(messages);
      res.render("index", { messages: messages });
    }
  });
});

app.post("/postMessage", function(req, res) {
  var newMessage = new Message(req.body);
  newMessage.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("there is a error when posting", err.errors);
      for (var e in err.errors) {
        req.flash("postMsg", err.errors[e].message);
      }
      res.render("validation", { errors: newMessage.errors });
    } else {
      console.log("success added a user");
      res.redirect("/");
    }
  });
});

app.listen(8000, function() {
  console.log("listening on port 8000");
});
```

```
index.ejs: 

<body>
    <h2>Welcome to Message Board </h2> 
    <div id='placeholder'>Placeholder</div>
    <form action='/postMessage' method='post' class='postForm'>
        <h4>Name:</h4>
        <input type='text' name='name'>
        <h4>Message:</h4>
        <input type='text' style="width: 600px; height: 100px;" name='message'><br>
        <button id='submitMessage' style='margin-left: 520px; background-color: darkorange;' type='submit'>Post Message</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        $('.postForm').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault()
            $.ajax({
                url: '/postMessage',
                method: 'POST',
                data: $(this).parent().serialize(),
                success: function(serverResponse){
                    console.log('ajax is working')
                    $('#placeholder').html(serverResponse) 
                }
            })
        })
    </script> 

validation.ejs: 

<body>
    <% if(messages.postMsg){ %>
        <% for(var x of messages.postMsg) {%>
            <h5 style='color: crimson'><%= x %></h5>
        <% } %>
    <% } %>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do two things:

1. Return from the API an erroneous response if something is not right (e.g. `400`, `Bad Request`).
2. Handle the [https://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/](http://ajax#fail) in your code to handle those cases.